# Webpage not opening on another machine on LAN

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server

Using a router in which 2 machines are connected.
on one i have installed Apache HTTPD (IP : 192.168.1.2).

Using localhost on that machine, i can see the webpage, but on another machine (192.168.1.5) when I am trying to see that webpage using IP address of the former (ie. 192.168.1.2). Its saying server not found.

ping works vice versa.

Comment: What about port 80? Is it open? You can try: `telnet 192.168.1.2 80` to check for port reachability.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure the firewall is disabled on the server with the webserver, if the website then becomes available, open whichever port the website is hosted on, probably 80 or 443.

Answer (score 0):

is apache listening on your lan ip address (192.168.1.2) or is it listening on the localhost ip address ( 127.0.0.1 ). Check the config file ( httpd.conf )

Answer (score 0):

Look at netstat -apn, and especially check that apache hasn't bound ipv6 only, as current distribution varieties of it are very liable to do that...